# Access SQL Query - Selecting middle section of many different types of strings

Tags: sql, split, ms-access-2007

How do i chose the middle section of a string when the desired section is surrounded by the same character "/", and the start of the string is not always at the same index?

```
e.g. "NWST/330/23/WT6" to "330" 

and  "NTW/1010/43/TY7" to "1010"

and  "TYQT/99/WYT3"    to "99"
```

I have tried combinations of SQL functions including `CharIndex`, `Len`, `Left`, `Right`, `Mid`, `InStr` and `InStRe`, Please HELP!?!?!?!

:(

Comment: what is the definition of 'middle section of a string'?

Comment: sorry i am a n00b, mate. i mighten be wording this right..? I want to run a query so that it refines the data in my example - so it creates a column that only returns the 2, 3, or 4 digit number after the first "/". any ideas?

Comment: yeah the characters between the first two slashes - however for some of the data it is actually the middle section (see last example). every input string contains either 2 or 3.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the VBA Split() function.  You give it a string and tell it what to use as the delimiter; it returns an array of substrings.  In your case, it seems you want the second substring, and since the array numbering is zero-based:

```
? Split("NWST/330/23/WT6", "/")(1)
330
```

You can't use that function directly in an Access query, but you can create a custom function which uses it.

```
Public Function CustomSplit(ByVal pInput As String) As String
    CustomSplit = Split(pInput, "/")(1)
End Function
```

Then, from the Immediate Window:

```
? CustomSplit("NWST/330/23/WT6")
330
```

So you could use CustomSplit() in a query you run from inside an Access session.  However, if you're using some other method (classic ASP, Dot.Net, etc) to query an Access database, user-defined functions are not available so you would need to use a different approach.

So if your text is in a field named raw_text, the query could be this:

```
SELECT
    raw_text,
    CustomSplit(raw_text) AS middle_section
FROM YourTableNameHere;
```

If you prefer a query without a custom function, you can use some of the functions you mentioned in your question.

```
SELECT
    raw_text,
    Mid(Left(raw_text, InStr(InStr(1, raw_text, "/") + 1,
        raw_text, "/") - 1), InStr(1, raw_text, "/") + 1)
        AS middle_section
FROM YourTableNameHere;
```

Either of those queries produces this as the output:

```
raw_text         middle_section
NWST/330/23/WT6  330
NTW/1010/43/TY7  1010
TYQT/99/WYT3     99
```

Comment: i would +1 but i dont have enough reputation haha thanks anyways mate

Comment: where exactly do i enter this code? 
with organizing my other data i have simply been typing the code into the query "Field:"
when i put this code into the field it says that it is too complex to run.
do you know what i am possibly doing wrong?

Comment: For eg: i have typed codes such as 
Mid(<str>,InStrRev(<str>,"/")+1) into the "Field:" section.
This code returns all that is after the last "/"

Comment: Create a new query and switch it to SQL View.  Copy the text of the last query from my answer and paste it into the SQL View, replacing any text which was already there (if any).  You will have to replace YourTableNameHere with the name of your table and raw_text with the name of the field which holds the text you want to parse.  Then click the button which has a red exclamation point to run it ... which displays the query results in datasheet view.

Comment: Mate you are an absolute champ. I really do appreciate your time. Thank you so much. I will get onto that and let you know how I go. Thanks again!

Comment: That worked great! THANK YOU! I didn't even realise where the SQL code was until now haha - a simple right click away! That helped me so much :) I think I understand how queries work a bit better too now. I am trying to slip your code into my original query now. So I only have to run the one query. I am having trouble though. I believe I have to use your code as a "subquery" in my original code. I have tried to add it in the SELECT, FROM, and WHERE sections. But once again have failed! Could I possibly get some more direction? I could send you my code if it would help :D ???

Comment: Hey mate. It is actually a effin huge data base. It's stored on the companies hard where in another city, and I've linked it up through our companies intranet to auto update my selected data tables. I wont be able to send you the data :( But maybe if I just send you my original code you could show me where/how I could possibly insert your code as a subquery? If its late there dw. There is no rush mate. I actually wont be at work again until the 24th of Jan.

Answer (score 0):

below should do it.

```sql
declare @input varchar(255);
declare @input2 varchar(255)
set @input = 'NTW/1010/43/TY7'

set @input2 = substring(@input,charindex('/', @input) + 1, len(@input))

select substring(@input2, 0, charindex('/', @input2))
```

hardly the most elegant but functional.

Comment: This appears to be TSQL rather than Access SQL.

Comment: yeah good spot! :) i read sql query and didnt register #access for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access installed, but this should work, or at least get you close:

```
=MID(<str>,INSTR(1,<str>,"/")+1,INSTR(INSTR(1,<str>,"/")+1,<str>,"/")-1)
```

Here is how to do it in Excel (which I tested)

```
=MID(A4,SEARCH("/",A4,1)+1,SEARCH("/",A4,SEARCH("/",A4)+1)-SEARCH("/",A4)-1)
```

and SQL (which I also tested)

```
declare @theStr VARCHAR(200)
set @theStr = 'NWST/330/23/WT6'

select SUBSTRING(@theStr,charindex('/',@theStr)+1,CHARINDEX('./',@theStr,2)+
       charindex('/',@theStr)-2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so quickly!
Sadly it did not work. It says "this expresion is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated."
I might be a bit confused when i said "SQL functions", i thought the functions i was using in the access query were called..? from what you posted i think i am mistaken...
Im sorry, i have done a little bit of work with VBA in excel but im only using access for the first time. I had already tried to imitate the excel formula but failed hard.
Any other suggestions? do i maybe have to run two queries instead?

Comment: Microsoft Access and Microsoft SQL use different function names.   The first example is using the functions within MS-Access, but since I don't have Access installed, I wanted to show you a couple examples in other tools, just to show how to accomplish what you want...

Comment: i can do what i want in excel but there is far too much data for it to run smoothly (and this will have to be done by many ppl in the future) - thats why i have been advised that it would work better in access, less likely to crash

Comment: I am not 100% of the access syntax, I would recommend breaking it apart, i.e.  do Mid(<str>,1,10)  first, see if that works, then add Mid(<str>,INSTR(1,"/",<str>)+1,99), see if that works, etc.  It could be the expression is too complex for Access, but I would input gradually to see if there is a typo first...

Comment: I just revised the syntax of access query, I had the parameters reversed.   If still doesn't work, send me you actual code and I'll take a peek

Comment: sorry, which parameters did you have reversed in the syntax?

Comment: The INSTR() function, should be <search_string>,<string to search for>

Comment: I believe i reversed they back correctly...
MID(<str>,INSTR(INSTR(1,"/",<str>)+1,"/",<str>)-1,INSTR(1,"/",<str>)+1,)
however it returned "#Func!" for all. Any ideas mate? Thank you so much for the help btw.

Comment: Mid(<str>,InStrRev(<str>,"/")+1) this code returns all that is after the last "/"

Comment: Left(<str>,InStr(<str>,"/")-1) and ive been using this to return the first part until the "/"

Comment: Why is it so hard to simply query the middle section! haha this is really bugging me. How would i go about using the SQL that you have provided to refine my data in Access? is it possible for me to write a macro that runs the query and then the SQL code you have provided?